# Access Firefox with Accessibility and Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

Is it possible to acccess the Firefox Application through accessibilty and read out the links in the open tabs? 
How could this be done with swift? Does somebody know a good tutorial for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research and now I can be sure. There is no way it can be done with accesibilty or applescript. 
The reason is that firefox does not support this in osx. Sad but hopefully it will change in the future.